# Getting error when using µ symbol in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, jaydata

Getting this error i am retriving data from web sql using jaydata.

`Error: Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 27-27 [µ] in expression [foodDetail.FoodItem.Vit_C__µg_]`.

My code is as below

```
<i>
  <li><span>Vitamin C</span><span style="float:right">{{foodDetail.FoodItem.Vit_C__µg_}}</span></li>
  <li><span>Vitamin B6</span><span style="float:right">{{foodDetail.FoodItem.Vit_B6__mg_}}</span></li>
</i>
```

Comment: Should be a restriction of Angular parser - and should be considered a bug probably; it's allowed to use this kind of symbols in JS identifiers. Have you submitted the bug to Angular team?

Comment: In fact, there's [one](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2174). I'd suggest checking the pull request issued for it.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try below:**

```
angular.module("test", [])
.run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.foodDetail = {
    FoodItem: {
      'Vit_C__µg_': 'Vit_C__µg_Val',
      'Vit_B6__mg_': 'Vit_B6__mg_Val',
    }
  };
});
```